# Elegantly avoid columns containing NaNs?

Tags: python, numpy

The next bit of code does exactly what i want it to do, but it is 'rather' unelegant and unpythonic, so the question is quite simple: how can this code be changed into something more elegant

```
import numpy
from scipy.stats import nanmean
A = [[1, numpy.nan, 2],[2,3,4], [2,3,4], [numpy.nan, 5, 5]]
A1 = numpy.array(A)
print A1

def dosomething(d2):
    a0 = d2[0, :]
    a1 = d2[1, :]
    a2 = d2[2, :]
    dnan = ~numpy.isnan(a0+a1+a2)
    a01 = (a0-numpy.mean(a0[dnan]))/numpy.std(a0[dnan])
    a11 = (a1-numpy.mean(a1[dnan]))/numpy.std(a1[dnan])
    a21 = (a2-numpy.mean(a2[dnan]))/numpy.std(a2[dnan])
    l = nanmean(numpy.array([a01,a11,a21]), axis=0)
    return l

print dosomething(A1)


[[  1.  nan   2.]
[  2.   3.   4.]
[  2.   3.   4.]
[ nan   5.   5.]]

[-1.  0.  1.]
```

Edit: i simplified it a bit more

Comment: yeah, i know, but i just gave the 3x3 sample to make it easier ofc-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `d2[:, dnan]` to select the wanted columns. (I'm assuming you want to process all rows unlike your current code)

```
def dosomething(d2):
    dnan = ~numpy.isnan(d2.sum(axis=0))
    validcols = d2[:, dnan]
    normalized = numpy.transpose((d2.T - numpy.mean(validcols, axis=1)) / numpy.std(validcols, axis=1))
    l = nanmean(normalized, axis=0)
    return l
```

Comment: looks nice, but you returned l will have the length of the dnan instead of the length of the initial array? (the index of each point should be the same index after the method)

Comment: @usethedeathstar Added transposes to the normalization. The problem with my previous version was that when I take the row-wise mean I get an 1D array as result, which NumPy treats as a row when subtracting from `d2`, while I want to subtract a column.

Comment: thanks, that works and looks a lot more elegant than what it was before

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to avoid all rows with NaNs, prefilter with a list comprehension to get rid of the rows you don't want, along the lines of:

```
filtered_rows = [r for r in all_rows where not numpy.nan in r]
```

and then do your work on `filtered_rows`. If memory is a problem, you could replace that with a function that yields only valid rows:

```
def filter_rows(*rows):
    for each_row in rows:
        if not numpy.nan in each_row:
            yield each_row

for r in filter_rows(*rows):
    # do something with r.
```

Comment: I did not spell out the fact that my "all_rows" is OP's list "A".  But it's a vanilla list comprehension.  AFAIK it also works in numpy.arrays as well as plain old python lists

Comment: would work, but dont you get a shorter list in return? (the index of each point is important, thats why i didnt use a list comprehension like you used)

Comment: Is the order of the components significant? If not, just filter them out at that level instead of on the list level.

Comment: yes, each index is linked to a spatial coordinate somewhere else in my code